# how to disable `alt-numkey` in bash shell

Tags: bash, bashrc, readline, inputrc

I can bounce between apps in Chrome OS by pressing `alt-N`, where N is the position of my app on the status bar. Useful!

But when I'm in the bash shell of my Nitrous.io box, pressing `alt-N` to bounce to a different app gives bash a command: `(arg: N)`.

What does the `(arg: N)` command do in bash? A five minute search taught me plenty of hotkeys, but none with *alt + number key*.

And can I disable it?

Comment: They are [readline arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Arguments). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562115/press-alt-numeric-in-bash-and-you-get-arg-numeric-what-is-that)  are some good explanations.

Comment: For anyone wanting to do this with Crostini, under the keyboard and mouse settings (for Terminal, not the general settings) you can enable the Alt + 1-9 keybinds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove them in an exactly same way as any other shortcut – with `bind -r`

```
for i in "-" {0..9}; do bind -r "\e$i"; done
```

If you hate loops, you may do it manually:

```
bind -r '\e-'
bind -r '\e0'
bind -r '\e1'
bind -r '\e2'
bind -r '\e3'
bind -r '\e4'
bind -r '\e5'
bind -r '\e6'
bind -r '\e7'
bind -r '\e8'
bind -r '\e9'
```

If you do not want this modifiers not only in Bash sessions but everywhere where GNU Readline provides them, add the following lines not in your `.bashrc` but in your `.inputrc`:

```
"\e-"
"\e0"
"\e1"
"\e2"
"\e3"
"\e4"
"\e5"
"\e6"
"\e7"
"\e8"
"\e9"
```

(Yes, just list them).

Comment: This worked for me in my regular terminal, but for some reason has not worked in guake. I wonder is there some other config that needs or should I report it to the maintainers.

Comment: This gives me `readline: ~/.inputrc: line 1: "\e-": no key sequence terminator`, and the same for all of the others.